# Flutter: How to draw a Bezier curve use gesture?

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, gesture

I want to make a page that can draw a **Bezier curve** dynamically using **gestures (select the endpoint then drag and drop)** like this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVA0Y20Pmdg). My app run on Android and Ubuntu.